# How to fix MariaDB Authentication Plugin - PAM?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, pam

I have installed MariaDB server on Ubuntu 18.04. I need PAM authentication plugin, therefore I followed the steps described here: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/configuring-pam-authentication-and-user-mapping-with-mariadb/, to install the plugin.

I have downloaded and installed PAM-mapper using:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MariaDB/server/10.1/plugin/auth_pam/mapper/pam_user_map.c
gcc pam_user_map.c -shared -lpam -fPIC -o pam_user_map.so
sudo install --mode=0755 pam_user_map.so /lib64/security/
```

Then I have created PAM policy:

```
sudo tee /etc/pam.d/mysql <<EOF
auth required pam_unix.so audit
account required pam_unix.so audit
auth sufficient /lib64/security/pam_user_map.so
EOF
```

To the file `/etc/security/user_map.conf` I have added the mapping I wanted to have, I have opened the access `/etc/shadow` as described in the tutorial.

Then, I have set everythinf up on the MariaDB side by using the following commands:

```
-- Install the plugin
INSTALL SONAME 'auth_pam';

-- Create the "dba" user
CREATE USER 'user_for_mapping'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dba'@'%';

-- Create an anonymous catch-all user that will use the PAM plugin and the mysql policy
CREATE USER ''@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam USING 'mysql';

-- Allow the anonymous user to proxy as the dba user
GRANT PROXY ON 'user_for_mapping'@'%' TO ''@'%';
```

Everything was working. Users from mapping file where mapped as they should be, users not mentioned in the mapping file were mapped to anonymous account ''@'%' as they should.
Nevertheless, from one day to another it has stopped working, even though nothing was changed in MariaDB settings (not sure if someone has introduced changes on Ubuntu side).

Now when I am trying to log in as before using:
`mysql -u ubuntu_user -p` or using `mysql -u '' -p` I get the same error message:

```
2019-11-19  9:37:56 11 [Warning] Access denied for user 'ubuntu_user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

even thought I am using the password.
From `mysql.log` file I can read `ubuntu_user@localhost as anonymous on` and then error again.

From file `auth.log` I can read the following:

```
Nov 19 09:37:27 host_name pkexec[34382]: shin: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/shin] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Nov 19 09:37:27 host_name pkexec[34396]: ubuntu_user: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/ubuntu_user] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
...
Nov 19 09:37:43 host_name sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

When I am using SHOW PLUGINS command in mysql, I can see that pam plugin is active. To the config file I have added `plugin_load_add = auth_pam`, but that still doesn't help.

Does anyone have any idea what can be the issue here and how could I solve that problem?